# Telegram бот возвращает приветсвие несколько раз при нажатии кнопки назад

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def genre(message):
    # Начальный раздел жанров

    if message.text == 'По жанру':

        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        item1 = types.KeyboardButton("Катастрофы")
        item2 = types.KeyboardButton("Комедии")
        item3 = types.KeyboardButton("Боевики")
        item4 = types.KeyboardButton("Ужасы")
        item5 = types.KeyboardButton("Мультфильмы")
        item6 = types.KeyboardButton("‍♀️Приключения")
        item7 = types.KeyboardButton("↩Назад")

        markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7)

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите интересующий вас жанр:', reply_markup=markup)
    elif message.text == "↩Назад":
        welcome(message)

    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    # Раздел жанры катастрофа     
    if message.text == 'Катастрофы':
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
        item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Титаник", callback_data='1.1')
        item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Выжить", callback_data='1.2')
        item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Смерч", callback_data='1.3')
        item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Метро", callback_data='1.4')
        item5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Разлом", callback_data='1.5')
        item6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Тунель: опасно для жизни", callback_data='1.6')
        item7 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("И грянул шторм", callback_data='1.7')
        item8 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("В изоляции", callback_data='1.8')
        item9 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Волна", callback_data='1.9')
        item10 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Черный краб", callback_data='1.10')

        markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, item8, item9, item10)

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите интересующий вас фильм:', reply_markup=markup)

    # Раздел жанры комедии
    if message.text == 'Комедии':
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
        item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Круэлла", callback_data='1.11')
        item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Мальчишник в Вегасе", callback_data='1.12')
        item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Мы - Миллеры", callback_data='1.13')
        item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Третий лишний", callback_data='1.14')
        item5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Большой Лебовски", callback_data='1.15')
        item6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Впритык", callback_data='1.16')
        item7 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Стажер", callback_data='1.17')
        item8 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Майор Пейн", callback_data='1.18')
        item9 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("(НЕ)идеальный мужчина", callback_data='1.19')
        item10 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Почему он?", callback_data='1.20')

        markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, item8, item9, item10)

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите интересующий вас фильм:', reply_markup=markup)

    # Раздел жанры боевики
    if message.text == 'Боевики':
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
        item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Гнев человеческий", callback_data='1.21')
        item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Леон", callback_data='1.22')
        item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Карты, деньги, два ствола", callback_data='1.23')
        item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Бесславные ублюдки", callback_data='1.24')
        item5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Майор Гром: Чумной Доктор", callback_data='1.25')
        item6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Джон Уик", callback_data='1.26')
        item7 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Троя", callback_data='1.27')
        item8 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Механик", callback_data='1.28')
        item9 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Стрелок", callback_data='1.29')
        item10 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Город грехов", callback_data='1.30')

        markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, item8, item9, item10)

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите интересующий вас фильм:', reply_markup=markup)

    # Раздел жанры ужасы
    if message.text == 'Ужасы':
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
        item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Поезд в Пусан", callback_data='1.31')
        item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Война миров Z", callback_data='1.32')
        item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Добро пожаловать в Zомбилэнд", callback_data='1.33')
        item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Заклятие", callback_data='1.34')
        item5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("28 дней спустя", callback_data='1.35')
        item6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Мгла", callback_data='1.36')
        item7 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Мумия", callback_data='1.37')
        item8 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Живое", callback_data='1.38')
        item9 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Дракула", callback_data='1.39')
        item10 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Хижина в лесу", callback_data='1.40')

        markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, item8, item9, item10)

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите интересующий вас фильм:', reply_markup=markup)

        # Раздел жанры мультфильмы
    if message.text == 'Мультфильмы':
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
        item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Лука", callback_data='1.41')
        item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Моана", callback_data='1.42')
        item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Ходячий замок", callback_data='1.43')
        item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Унесенные призраками", callback_data='1.44')
        item5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Король лев", callback_data='1.45')
        item6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Зов предков", callback_data='1.46')
        item7 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Валли", callback_data='1.47')
        item8 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Корпорация монстров", callback_data='1.48')
        item9 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Мулан", callback_data='1.49')
        item10 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Вокруг света за 80 дней", callback_data='1.50')

        markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, item8, item9, item10)

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите интересующий вас фильм:', reply_markup=markup)

        # Раздел жанры приключения    
    if message.text == '‍♀️Приключения':

        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
        item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Выживший", callback_data='1.51')
        item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Парк Юрского периода", callback_data='1.52')
        item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Анчартед: На картах не значится", callback_data='1.53')
        item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Кон - тики", callback_data='1.54')
        item5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Круиз по джунглям", callback_data='1.55')
        item6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Время первых", callback_data='1.56')
        item7 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Тайны печати дракона", callback_data='1.57')
        item8 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Восточный ветер", callback_data='1.58')
        item9 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Эбигейл", callback_data='1.59')
        item10 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Эспен в королевстве троллей", callback_data='1.60')

        markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, item8, item9, item10)

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите интересующий вас фильм:', reply_markup=markup)

    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    # Начальный раздел по стране

    elif message.text == 'По стране':

        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        item1 = types.KeyboardButton("Норвегия")
        item2 = types.KeyboardButton("Россия")
        item3 = types.KeyboardButton("Великобритания")
        item4 = types.KeyboardButton("Франция")
        item5 = types.KeyboardButton("США")
        item6 = types.KeyboardButton("↩Назад")

        markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6)

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите интересующую вас страну:', reply_markup=markup)

    elif message.text == "↩Назад":
        welcome(message)

    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    # Раздел по стране - Новервегия     

    if message.text == 'Норвегия':
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
        item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Худший человек на свете", callback_data='2.1')
        item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Тысячу раз «спокойной ночи»", callback_data='2.2')
        item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Охотники за головами", callback_data='2.3')
        item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Король чёртова острова", callback_data='2.4')
        item5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Гунда", callback_data='2.5')

        markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5)

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Топ-5 фильмов Норвегии:', reply_markup=markup)

    # Раздел по стране - Россия      

    if message.text == 'Россия':
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
        item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Брат", callback_data='2.6')
        item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Дурак", callback_data='2.7')
        item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Легенда №17", callback_data='2.8')
        item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("О чём говорят мужчины", callback_data='2.9')
        item5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Огонь", callback_data='2.10')

        markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5)

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Топ-5 фильмов России:', reply_markup=markup)

    # Раздел по стране - Великобритания      

    if message.text == 'Великобритания':
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
        item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Эмма", callback_data='2.11')
        item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Три секунды", callback_data='2.12')
        item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Гонка века", callback_data='2.13')
        item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Две королевы", callback_data='2.14')
        item5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Код «Красный»", callback_data='2.15')

        markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5)

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Топ-5 фильмов Великобритании:', reply_markup=markup)

    # Раздел по стране - Франция     

    if message.text == 'Франция':
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
        item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Расправь крылья", callback_data='2.16')
        item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Прекрасная эпоха", callback_data='2.17')
        item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Как прогулять школу с пользой", callback_data='2.18')
        item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Приключения Реми", callback_data='2.19')
        item5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Обещание на рассвете", callback_data='2.20')

        markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5)

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Топ-5 фильмов Франции:', reply_markup=markup)

    # Раздел по стране - США     

    if message.text == 'США':
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
        item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Побег из Шоушенка", callback_data='2.21')
        item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Начало", callback_data='2.22')
        item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Темный рыцарь", callback_data='2.23')
        item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Зеленая книга", callback_data='2.24')
        item5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Волк с Уолл-стрит", callback_data='2.25')

        markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5)

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Топ-5 фильмов США:', reply_markup=markup)

    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    # Начальный раздел по книгам

    elif message.text == 'По книгам':
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
        item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Фантастические твари и где они обитают", callback_data='3.1')
        item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Голодные игры", callback_data='3.2')
        item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Марсианин", callback_data='3.3')
        item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Бегущий в лабиринте", callback_data='3.4')
        item5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Дивергент", callback_data='3.5')
        item6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Сумерки", callback_data='3.6')
        item7 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("День триффидов", callback_data='3.7')
        item8 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Я – легенда", callback_data='3.8')
        item9 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Война миров", callback_data='3.9')
        item10 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Властелин колец", callback_data='3.10')

        markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item7, item8, item9, item10)

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите интересующий вас фильм по книге:', reply_markup=markup)

    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Начальный раздел по настроению

    elif message.text == 'По настроению':

        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        item1 = types.KeyboardButton("Веселое")
        item2 = types.KeyboardButton("Грустное")
        item3 = types.KeyboardButton("Загадочное")
        item4 = types.KeyboardButton("Мотивирующее")
        item5 = types.KeyboardButton("Романтичное")
        item6 = types.KeyboardButton("↩Назад")

        markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6)

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Какое у вас настроение:', reply_markup=markup)

    elif message.text == "↩Назад":
        welcome(message)

    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    # Раздел по настроению - веселое     

    if message.text == 'Веселое':
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
        item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Отпуск по обмену", callback_data='4.1')
        item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Маска", callback_data='4.2')
        item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Привет, Джули!", callback_data='4.3')
        item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Мамма миа!", callback_data='4.4')
        item5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Октябрьское небо", callback_data='4.5')
        item6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Хорошо быть тихоней", callback_data='4.6')
        item7 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Между небом и землей", callback_data='4.7')
        item8 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Семья напрокат", callback_data='4.8')
        item9 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("10 причин моей ненависти", callback_data='4.9')
        item10 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Тайная жизнь пчел", callback_data='4.10')

        markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, item8, item9, item10)

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите интересующий вас фильм:', reply_markup=markup)

        # Раздел по настроению - грустное

    if message.text == 'Грустное':
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
        item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Мальчик в полосатой пижаме", callback_data='4.11')
        item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Хорошие дети не плачут", callback_data='4.12')
        item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Дневник памяти", callback_data='4.13')
        item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("До встречи с тобой", callback_data='4.14')
        item5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("В метре друг от друга", callback_data='4.15')
        item6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Мост в Терабитию", callback_data='4.16')
        item7 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Куда приводят мечты", callback_data='4.17')
        item8 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Виноваты звезды", callback_data='4.18')
        item9 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Я Кристина", callback_data='4.19')
        item10 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Класс", callback_data='4.20')

        markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, item8, item9, item10)

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите интересующий вас фильм:', reply_markup=markup)

        # Раздел по настроению - таинственное

    if message.text == 'Загадочное':
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
        item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Другие", callback_data='4.21')
        item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Знакомьтесь, Джо Блэк", callback_data='4.22')
        item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Дориан Грей", callback_data='4.23')
        item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Тело", callback_data='4.24')
        item5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Сомния", callback_data='4.25')
        item6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Сонная лощина", callback_data='4.26')
        item7 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Ключ от всех дверей", callback_data='4.27')
        item8 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Знамение", callback_data='4.28')
        item9 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Гоголь. Вий", callback_data='4.29')
        item10 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Приют", callback_data='4.30')

        markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, item8, item9, item10)

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите интересующий вас фильм:', reply_markup=markup)

        # Раздел по настроению - мотивирующее

    if message.text == 'Мотивирующее':
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
        item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Одержимость", callback_data='4.31')
        item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Скрытые фигуры", callback_data='4.32')
        item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Каждое воскресенье", callback_data='4.33')
        item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Не волнуйся, он далеко не уйдет", callback_data='4.34')
        item5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("В погоне за счастьем", callback_data='4.35')
        item6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Человек, который изменил все", callback_data='4.36')
        item7 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Я — Сэм", callback_data='4.37')
        item8 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("127 часов", callback_data='4.38')
        item9 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Серфер души", callback_data='4.39')
        item10 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Спасительный рассвет", callback_data='4.40')

        markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, item8, item9, item10)

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите интересующий вас фильм:', reply_markup=markup)
        
        
            # Раздел по настроению - Романтичное

    if message.text == 'Романтичное':
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
        item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("365 дней", callback_data='4.41')
        item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("После", callback_data='4.42')
        item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Секретарша", callback_data='4.43')
        item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Будка поцелуев", callback_data='4.44')
        item5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Предложение", callback_data='4.45')
        item6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Звезда родилась", callback_data='4.46')
        item7 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Тепло наших тел", callback_data='4.47')
        item8 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Пятьдесят оттенков серого", callback_data='4.48')
        item9 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Золушка", callback_data='4.49')
        item10 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Он - дракон", callback_data='4.50')

        markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, item8, item9, item10)

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите интересующий вас фильм:', reply_markup=markup)
```

[image: Возвращает 3 раза приветственное сообщение при нажатии кнопки назад]

Answer (score 1):

У тебя два elif с приветствием в одной функции. Один ниже "По стране", другой ниже "По жанру". Убери один из них.

Comment: Убрала, но проблема не исчезла

Comment: А нет, их 3. Под "По настроению" ещё есть.

Comment: Я везде по убирала, но все равно проблему не решило

Comment: Проблема решена, спасибо))